# How to get scalebars continously output inside a while loop tkinter

Tags: python, get, while-loop, tkinter

I programmed a gui with tkinter and implemented a scalebar to vary a variable.
I'm trying to get the output of this scalebar inside a while loop.
What should happen:

1. Button press status = True
2. reading scalebar with get() method
3. pass variable to an other function (play sound with certain delay)
4. check scalebar -> 1.
5. Second button press set status = False -> exit while loop

My code got stuck and I can't change the scalebar when I am inside the while loop and I hade to force quit my code

I hope you have any idea! Code example is below, if you need more or the entire sourcecode let me know

Best regards,

SevenDeath

```
class FunctionClassTest:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def intimeSTOP(self):
        self.Test = False

    def intime(self):
        self.test=True
        while self.test:
            self.TestTmp = scalebarTime.get()
            if self.TestTmp < 0:
...
               playsound
...
online = FunctionClassTest()

buttonC = Button(window, text="Test On", command=online.intime)
buttonD = Button(window, text="Test Off", command=online.intimeSTOP)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the while loop. It conflicts with the Tkinter loop and effectively locks up the GUI, while continuously executing the loop, making the GUI unresponsive. One option you have to handle a simultaneous task easily is the `after` method. Here's an example:

```
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.timer = None # initalize timer variable

        self.slide = Scale(self)
        self.slide.pack()

        Button(self, text='go', command=self._start).pack()
        Button(self, text='stop', command=self._stop).pack()

    def _start(self):
        if self.slide.get() > 0:
            # ... code here ... ie, print self.slide.get()
            # set timer to after method, calling it every 1000ms
            self.timer = self.after(1000, self._start)

    def _stop(self):
        if self.timer is not None:
            # cancel timer, stopping the _start method from looping
            self.after_cancel(self.timer)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
app.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Refer to: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method for more info on the `after` method.